# Django ошибки CSRF (CSRF token missing or incorrect., CSRF cookie not set.)

Tags: django, csrf

Есть форма логина, если убрать обвес, то:

```
<form method="post" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <fieldset>
    {{ form.username.errors }}
    {% render_field form.username %}
    {{ form.password.errors }}
    {% render_field form.password %}
    <div class="login-submit-holder">
      <button class="login-submit">Войти</button>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

CBV:

```
from django.utils.http import urlencode, is_safe_url
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView as BaseLoginView,


class LoginView(BaseLoginView):
    form_class = AuthenticationForm
    redirect_authenticated_user = True

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()

        username = self.request.GET.get('username')
        if username:
            initial['username'] = username

        return initial

    def get_success_url(self):
        redirect_to = self.request.POST.get(
            self.redirect_field_name,
            self.request.GET.get(self.redirect_field_name, '')
        )
        url_is_safe = is_safe_url(
            url=redirect_to,
            allowed_hosts=self.get_success_url_allowed_hosts(),
            require_https=self.request.is_secure(),
        )
        default_page_url = get_default_page_url(self.request.user)
        if not url_is_safe:
            return default_page_url if default_page_url else resolve_url(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)

        return redirect_to

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'vk_registration_url': '{}?{}'.format(
                reverse('auth:social:begin', args=('vk-oauth2',)),
                urlencode({
                    'next': reverse('desktop:index'),
                    'landing': self.request.GET.get('ref_landing', '')
                })
            )
        })
        return context
```

`get_default_page_url` - возвращает ссылку куда отправляется пользователь после логина (для разных типов пользователей своя)

`vk_registration_url` - нужна чтобы в форме нарисовать альтернативный логин через Вк

Заметил в логах следующее:

```
2020-07-07 17:24:02,933 WARNING  Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /profile/login/
2020-07-07 17:24:12,217 WARNING  Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /profile/login/
```

Подменил стандартный csrf_failure чтобы посмотреть подробнее что приходит с запросом:

```
CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW = 'website_apps.common.views.log.csrf_failure'


import logging

from django.views.csrf import csrf_failure as django_csrf_failure
from django.utils import timezone

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def csrf_failure(request, reason=""):
    logger.error(
        (
            '{} {}, path: {}, Proto: {}, Method: {}\n'
            'User: {}\n'
            'Headers: {}\n'
            'Cookies: {}\n'
            'Session: {}\n'
            '{}'
        ).format(
            timezone.now(),
            reason,
            request.path,
            request.scheme,
            request.method,
            str(request.user) + ' (id=' + str(request.user.pk) + ')'
            if request.user.is_authenticated else
            'unknown',
            request.META,
            request.COOKIES,
            dict(request.session),
            ('Post data: ' + str(request.POST)) if request.method == "POST" else ''
        )
    )
    return django_csrf_failure(request, reason)
```

Вот что получилось на выходе:

```
2020-07-07 17:24:02.929199+00:00 CSRF token missing or incorrect., path: /profile/login/, Proto: https, Method: POST                       
User: <user_name> (id=<id>)                                                                                                                                     
Headers: {'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST', 'QUERY_STRING': '', 'SCRIPT_NAME': '', 'PATH_INFO': '/profile/login/', 'wsgi.multithread': True, 'wsgi.multiprocess': True, 'REMOTE_ADDR'
: '<ip>', 'REMOTE_HOST': '<ip>', 'REMOTE_PORT': 0, 'SERVER_NAME': '127.0.0.1', 'SERVER_PORT': '8000', 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'upgrade', 'HTTP_HOST': '<host_name>', 'HTTP_X_REAL_IP': '<ip>', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR': '<ip>', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST': '<host>', 'HTTP_X_FORWAR
DED_PROTO': 'https', 'CONTENT_LENGTH': '135', 'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL': 'max-age=0', 'HTTP_ORIGIN': '<origin>', 'HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS': '
1', 'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 9; ru-ru; Redmi Note 7 Build/PKQ1.180904.001) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/71.0.3578.141 Mobile Safari/537.36 XiaoMi/MiuiBrowser/12.3.5-g', 'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9
,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8', 'HTTP_REFERER': '<host>/profile/login/', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip, deflate', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 
'ru-RU,en-US;q=0.9', 'HTTP_COOKIE': 'csrftoken=QAUTtSScKPlDNHM9yMdY3BKxcTgtA6WNzxOuJCFtuBtGto8DgBvT0BYYTlJs5TnS; sessionid=kzk59o5bc8f6fg8xha4y0krebzgxaky4', 'CSRF_COOKIE': 
'QAUTtSScKPlDNHM9yMdY3BKxcTgtA6WNzxOuJCFtuBtGto8DgBvT0BYYTlJs5TnS'}                                                                                                          
Cookies: {'csrftoken': 'QAUTtSScKPlDNHM9yMdY3BKxcTgtA6WNzxOuJCFtuBtGto8DgBvT0BYYTlJs5TnS', 'sessionid': 'kzk59o5bc8f6fg8xha4y0krebzgxaky4'}                                  
Session: {'_auth_user_id': '<id>', '_auth_user_backend': 'website_apps.users.utils.auth_backends.ModelBackend', '_auth_user_hash': '<hash>'}                                                                                                 
Post data: <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['uSEJvk1xMtxZ80q62FzoVmnGdqQG8E6bdaXjQAzw2nXqyLVz2PudvxpqkRo559cd'], 'username': ['<user_name>'], 'password': ['<password>']}> 

2020-07-07 17:24:12.216057+00:00 CSRF cookie not set., path: /profile/login/, Proto: https, Method: POST
User: unknown                                                                                                                                                             
Headers: {'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST', 'QUERY_STRING': '', 'SCRIPT_NAME': '', 'PATH_INFO': '/profile/login/', 'wsgi.multithread': True, 'wsgi.multiprocess': True, 'REMOTE_ADDR'
: '<ip>', 'REMOTE_HOST': '<ip>', 'REMOTE_PORT': 0, 'SERVER_NAME': '127.0.0.1', 'SERVER_PORT': '8000', 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'upgrade', 'HTTP_HOST': '<host>', 'HTTP_X_REAL_IP': '<ip>', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR': '<ip>', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST': '<host>', 'HTTP_X_FORWAR
DED_PROTO': 'https', 'CONTENT_LENGTH': '847', 'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL': 'max-age=0', 'HTTP_ORIGIN': 'null', 'HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS': '1', 'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/x
-www-form-urlencoded', 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 9; ru-ru; Redmi Note 7 Build/PKQ1.180904.001) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Ch
rome/71.0.3578.141 Mobile Safari/537.36 XiaoMi/MiuiBrowser/12.3.5-g', 'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
 'HTTP_REFERER': '<host>/profile/login/', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip, deflate', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'ru-RU,en-US;q=0.9'}
Cookies: {}                                          
Session: {}                                                                                             
Post data: <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['2FEKjXzewyJzJ7xXgZa0NyExZ2KlN0bqLXXkEd7dMs909S2qg95PnJGh6tiKKvhs'], 'username': ['<user_name>'], 'password': ['<password>']}>
```

Как видно, csrf токен в заголовках и cookie и в теле запроса отличаются, поэтому валидацию не проходит.

Воспроизвести не удалось, пробовал с разных браузеров, в т.ч. мобильных - такого не наблюдается.

В чем может быть причина, почему токен в теле запроса оказывается другой?

Comment: Покажите соответствующий форме views

Comment: @andreymal добавил

Comment: На первый взгляд криминала не видно. А что насчёт попробовать в другом браузере? Вдруг это проблема в MiuiBrowser

Comment: @andreymal все самые распространенные перепробовал. chrome, yandex, safari. на мобилках в том числе. судя по тому что нет массовых жалоб проблема достаточно редкая